# How to export certificate from AWS Certificate M to import into java keystore at runtime without storing the certificate physically on my ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, export, runtime, aws-acm-certificate

I have an application which uses the certificate from Java key store which is physically stored on ec2 machine.I want to use the certificate from ACM directly at runtime without storing it on ec2 server.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You **can't export** AWS ACM certificates. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/export-private.html):

> You **cannot export** a publicly trusted ACM certificate or its private key.

If you want to use them with your instances, you either have to front it with **load balancer** or CloudFront where you can deploy the ACM certs. Other options on how you can use ACM are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html).

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_ExportCertificate.html 

this will return 3 things, "certificate", "certificateChain" and "privateKey"

Comment: @kewur this is for private ACM only. Op wants to use public ACM.